# vars not holding proper value after localStorage.getItem('key')

Tags: javascript, variables

My code works fine up until I try to save my data, exit out, then reopen then load saved data. I save using localStorage.setItem('key', value) then I load using localStorage.getItem('key'), but after I load my vars are not holding the right values. Is localStorage.getItem('key') returning a string, because 1 +1 = 2, not 11 like it's displaying. please help.

The page itself is stored on my PC not online, I'm opening it up with Google Chrome. I run Windows Edge. When I try opening this with Internet Explorer, forget about localStorage.set/getItem all together. I've tried just running my code with the variables then try to save and load. (note:All my code works flawlessly until I try to save the variables, then reload them). I'm working on a video game so I need to be able to save my variables. And since I'm not sure where the problem in my code lies, I'm sorry but I see no other option than to post about 180 lines of code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="black" >
        <font color="white" >

<progress id="myProgress" value="10" max="10"></progress><br>
<p id='demo5' ;></p>
<button id="enemy" type="button" onclick="dealDamage(), imageSwap()"><img 
id="enemy1" src="Game_Images/smiley_1.png"></button>
<button id="spriteTest" type="button" onclick="imageSwap2()"><img 
id="enemy2" src="Game_Images/smiley_1.png"></button><br>
<button id="upgrade" type="button" onclick="upgradeClickDamage()"> 
</button>
<button type="button" onclick="moreGold()">More Gold</button><br>
<button type="button" onclick="saveGame()">Save Game</button>
<button type="button" onclick="loadGame()">Load Game</button>

<p id='demo' ;></p> 
<p id='demo2' ;></p> 
<p id='demo3' ;></p> 
<p id='demo4' ;></p>

<script>

var clickDamage = 1;
var gold = 0;
var stage = 1;
var enemyNum = 1;
var enemiesTotal = 10;
var enemiesKilled = 0;
var cost = 100;
var enemyHPTotal = 10;
var enemyHPCurrent = 10;

document.getElementById("upgrade").innerHTML = "Upgrade click damage for:" 
+ cost + " gold.";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Gold:   " + gold;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Stage:   " + stage;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Enemies Killed This Stage:" 
+ enemiesKilled + "/" + enemiesTotal;
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Click Damage:" + 
clickDamage;
document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = "Enemy HP remaining:" + 
enemyHPCurrent + "/" + enemyHPTotal;

function imageSwap() {
    var image = document.getElementById("enemy1");
    if (image.src.match("Game_Images/smiley_1")){
      image.src="Game_Images/smiley_2.png"
    }
    else if (image.src.match("Game_Images/smiley_2")){
      image.src="Game_Images/smiley_3.png"
    }
    else {
    image.src="Game_Images/smiley_1.png"
    }
}

function imageSwap2(){
    var image2 = document.getElementById("enemy2");
    if(image2.src.match("Game_Images/smiley_1")){
      setTimeout(image2.src="Game_Images/smiley_2.png", 300);
    }
    else if(image2.src.match("Game_Images/smiley_2")){
      setTimeout(image2.src="Game_Images/smiley_3.png", 300);
    }
     else {
      setTimeout(image2.src="Game_Images/smiley_1.png", 300);
    }
}

function dealDamage() {
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value -= clickDamage;
//If enemy is hit but does not die
if(document.getElementById("myProgress").value >= 1){
    enemyHPCurrent = document.getElementById("myProgress").value
    enemyHPTotal = document.getElementById("myProgress").max
    document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = "Enemy HP remaining:" 
+ enemyHPCurrent + "/" + enemyHPTotal;
}

//If enemy is killed and there are remaining enemies in the current stage
if (document.getElementById("myProgress").value == 0 && enemyNum < 10) {
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = 
document.getElementById("myProgress").max;
    gold += (1 * stage);
    enemyHPTotal = document.getElementById("myProgress").value;
    enemyNum += 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Gold:   " + gold;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Stage:   " + stage;
        enemiesKilled += 1;
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Enemies Killed This 
Stage:" + enemiesKilled + "/" + enemiesTotal;
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Click Damage:" + 
clickDamage;
    enemyHPCurrent = enemyHPTotal;
    document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = "Enemy HP remaining:" 
+ enemyHPCurrent + "/" + enemyHPTotal;

}

//If the enemy is killed and it is the last enemy of the current stage
if (document.getElementById("myProgress").value == 0 && enemyNum == 10) {
    document.getElementById("myProgress").max += 1; 
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = 
document.getElementById("myProgress").max;
    gold += (1 * stage);
    enemyNum = 1;
    stage += 1;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Gold:   " + gold;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Stage:   " + stage;
    enemiesKilled = 0;
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Enemies Killed This 
Stage:" + enemiesKilled + "/" + enemiesTotal;
    document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Click Damage:" + 
clickDamage;
    enemyHPTotal = document.getElementById("myProgress").max;
    enemyHPCurrent = enemyHPTotal;
    document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = "Enemy HP remaining:" 
+ enemyHPCurrent + "/" + enemyHPTotal;

}

}

function upgradeClickDamage() {
  if (gold >= cost) {
    gold -= cost;
    clickDamage += 1;
    cost += 100;
    document.getElementById("messageBox").innerHTML = 
    "Congratulations!!! You just upgraded your click damage."
document.getElementById("upgrade").innerHTML = "Upgrade click damage 
for:" + cost + " gold.";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Gold:   " + gold;
document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = "Click Damage:" + 
clickDamage;

}
  else if (gold < cost) {
    document.getElementById("messageBox").innerHTML = "You don't have 
enough gold for this upgrade."
  }
}
function moreGold() {
     gold += 100;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Gold:   " + gold;
}

function saveGame(){
//save all vars
    localStorage.setItem('CLICKDAMAGE', clickDamage);
    localStorage.setItem('GOLD', gold); 
    localStorage.setItem('STAGE', stage);
    localStorage.setItem('ENEMYNUM', enemyNum);
    localStorage.setItem('ENEMIESTOTAL', enemiesTotal);
    localStorage.setItem('ENEMIESKILLED', enemiesKilled);
    localStorage.setItem('COST', cost);
    localStorage.setItem('ENEMYHPTOTAL', enemyHPTotal);
    localStorage.setItem('ENEMYHPCURRENT', enemyHPCurrent);
}

function loadGame(){
//load all vars
    clickDamage = localStorage.getItem('CLICKDAMAGE');
    gold = localStorage.getItem('GOLD');    
    stage = localStorage.getItem('STAGE');
    enemyNum = localStorage.getItem('ENEMYNUM');
    enemiesTotal = localStorage.getItem('ENEMIESTOTAL');
    enemiesKilled = localStorage.getItem('ENEMIESKILLED');
    cost = localStorage.getItem('COST');
    enemyHPTotal = localStorage.getItem('ENEMYHPTOTAL');
    enemyHPCurrent = localStorage.getItem('ENEMYHPCURRENT');
}

</script>
<div id="messageBox"></div>
</font>

    </body>
</html>
```

I expected all variables to function properly after loading. 
gold, cost, and enemiesKilled are all affected by this same problem. If gold = 1, and I save that variable then load that variable later, then add 1 again, I get 11, not 2. With cost, if cost = 100, then I save, then I load later, then I add 100 to cost, cost = 100100 not 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This will restate a bit of what you hypothesized in your question for the sake of completeness)

If you look at the documentation for [`Storage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), it says:

> Return value
>   A [`DOMString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) containing the value of the key. If the key does not exist, null is returned.

This means that no matter what data type you give in `setItem`, the output of `getItem` will always be a string. This is easy to test in the console:

```
localStorage.setItem("test", 1);
> undefined
localStorage.getItem("test");
> "1"
```

When you add a string to a number, it just concatenates the two together. In your case, you're adding `"1" + 1` which becomes `"11"` instead of adding `1 + 1` which would be `2`. The solution is to convert the number string into a number, which can be done several ways, but is easiest to do (in my opinion) by simply prefixing the expression with a `+`.

```
+localStorage.getItem("test");
> 1
```

Comment: I don't need the var added right away. I need it to be the saved number right away then add to it later. What is 1 more way to convert that to a number?

Comment: The way I use `+` there is as a prefix operator. It doesn't add anything, but it will coerce a string into a number. To answer your question though, `parseInt(x)`, `parseFloat(x)`, `Number(x)`, and `new Number(x)` will all convert a string to a number as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `localStorage.setItem` converts all passed values to string. Once you call `localStorage.getItem` you are getting back string value.

So you are trying to concatenate string and number `"1" + 1 === "11"`.

To prevent this behavior you need to manually convert values to stringified JSON:

```
localStorage.setItem('CLICKDAMAGE', JSON.stringify(clickDamage));
```

And then parse it back:

```
clickDamage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('CLICKDAMAGE'));
```

Comment: I used -    clickDamage = Number(localStorage.getItem('CLICKDAMAGE'));    I'm not sure what JSON.parse does yet, I only know html and a bit of javascript

Comment: @JohnThompson, [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) is a standard JS method that takes a string and formats it to JS value (number, boolean, ...) or object.
For your current case `Number(...);` will work fine, but `JSON.parse` is a more generic solution.